# Replace each column within a dataframe with matches from a lookup table

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup

I've got this `data.frame` called `table_1` with a structure like this:

```
      p_id   rd1  rd2    rd3
     <fctr><fctr><fctr><fctr>
   1    1     5     4     6
   2    2     3     1     1
   3    3     6     6     5
   4    4     1     5     2
   5    5     4     1     4
```

I also have this other `data.frame` with `p_id` and `p_scr` that is set up like so:

```
      p_id  p_scr
     <fctr><fctr>
   1    1     11 
   2    2     22
   3    3     33
   4    4     44
   5    5     55
   6    6     66
```

My goal: For every column in `table_1`, I want to replace all of the entries of `rd1`, `rd2`, and `rd3` with the lookup values in the table `p_scr`.

```
      p_id   rd1  rd2    rd3
     <fctr><fctr><fctr><fctr>
   1    1     55    44    66
   2    2     33    11    11
   3    3     66    66    55
   4    4     11    55    22
   5    5     44    11    44
```

I suspect this will use `mapply` or `lapply` with `match` but I haven't found a good example like this.  I am also familiar with`mutate`and I suspect that could be used here, too.  Open to any suggestions.  Note: this is a simplified version of my actual data.

Comment: The problem is not totally clear but if you want a primer on apply family of funcitons, please consult the R base package for all the functions and their detailed usage with examples.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/00Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I have corrected this code to match your data structure which are all factors.  Use your rd values in t to index your reference lookup table by setting rownames of ref table to p_ids.

I use different values for p_ids to highlight the indexing by p_id rownames, not by position.

```
# t is your df; ref is your lookup table
t <- data.frame(p_id=factor(c(10,20,30,40,50)),
            rd1=factor(c(5,3,6,1,4)*10),
            rd2=factor(c(4,1,6,5,1)*10),
            rd3=factor(c(6,1,5,2,4)*10))
ref <- data.frame(p_id=factor(c(10,20,30,40,50,60)), 
              p_scr=factor(c(11,22,33,44,55,66)))

t
#   p_id rd1 rd2 rd3
# 1   10  50  40  60
# 2   20  30  10  10
# 3   30  60  60  50
# 4   40  10  50  20
# 5   50  40  10  40

ref
#   p_id p_scr
# 1   10    11
# 2   20    22
# 3   30    33
# 4   40    44
# 5   50    55
# 6   60    66

# assuming p_id is unique, set rownames of ref lookup table to p_id to allow for indexing by p_id
rownames(ref) <- ref$p_id
rownames(ref) # character values, not numeric
# [1] "10" "20" "30" "40" "50" "60"

# ref lookup table now looks like this
ref
#    p_id p_scr
# 10   10    11
# 20   20    22
# 30   30    33
# 40   40    44
# 50   50    55
# 60   60    66

# single case, ref rownames are character vectors, we want to index with corresponding character vector from t
as.character(t$rd1)
# [1] "50" "30" "60" "10" "40"
ref[as.character(t$rd1),]$p_scr # use character values of rd1 to index, matching the character values of rownames
# [1] 55 33 66 11 44
# Levels: 11 22 33 44 55 66

# apply to each rd column, returns the character values of p_scr factor
apply(t[,2:ncol(t)], 2, function(x) ref[as.character(x),]$p_scr)
# converts to numeric the character values of p_scr factor
apply(t[,2:ncol(t)], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(ref[as.character(x),]$p_scr)))


# NOTE: the previous answer I gave does not work, why?
ref[t$rd1,]$p_scr # gives incorrect order
# [1] 44 22 55 11 33
# Levels: 11 22 33 44 55 66
# NOTE structure of t
str(t)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ p_id: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","20","30",..: 1 2 3 4 5
# $ rd1 : Factor w/ 5 levels "10","30","40",..: 4 2 5 1 3
# $ rd2 : Factor w/ 4 levels "10","40","50",..: 2 1 4 3 1
# $ rd3 : Factor w/ 5 levels "10","20","40",..: 5 1 4 2 3

# Do you see the character vs integer values of the factor t$rd1
t$rd1
# [1] 50 30 60 10 40
# Levels: 10 30 40 50 60
# The levels of t$rd1: "10", "30", "40", "50", "60", which correspond to 4 2 5 1 3 position
# In the case of ref[t$rd1] you are using the integer values of t$rd1 and indexing ref by position: ref[c(4,2,5,1,3)] so your output is c(44, 22, 55, 11, 33)
# In the case of ref[as.character(t$rd1) you are using the character values of t$rd1 and indexing ref by rownames: ref[c("50", "30", "60", "10", "40")] so your output is c(55, 33, 66 11, 44)
```

Note be careful with indexing if your data are factors, always check the structure and integer values. Observe:

```
n <- 1:5 # numeric
n
f <- factor(n, levels=5:1) # factor
f
levels(f)

# consequence when used to index
letters[n]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
letters[f]
[1] "e" "d" "c" "b" "a"
```

Comment: awesome. just awesome.  This worked amazingly.  I guess I'm still confused as to why `rownames(ref)` and allowing indexing worked here. I'll have to keep looking at the single-use case (thanks for adding that). Thank you!

Comment: @jmb277 just edited to add caution if your data are factors, please note the levels of factors

Comment: huh - I did some spot-checks and it seems to work. I think the data is still str formats.  I guess I'm unclear if this will be an issue here.  The results of the `apply` are either a number or an NA which is ok w/ me.

Comment: uh, yeah - i think I've run into this issue just now.  When I try to convert the looked up data to numeric it gets altered to numbers that I do not recognize.

Comment: can the numeric conversion be done within this part? `apply(t[,2:ncol(t)], 2, function(x) ref[x,]$p_scr)` - I am unclear how to apply this. - actually, I figured it out. just now.

Comment: @jmb277 I deleted my comment, actually can you edit your question and put the output of `str(t)` and `str(ref)` for me.  I don't want to confuse you, and I will edit my answer to match the structure of your data frames.

Comment: @jmb277 I looked at your question again, it's now clear to me you are working with factors.  I have edited the answer, note the previous answer is incorrect when dealing with factors.  Factors have character representation and integer values, I hope the notes on the corrected answer makes this clear.

Comment: @r-s - thank you again! I think I understand it a bit more - at least where the problems can arise.  I'll need to study it in further detail as I recognize that understanding the data types I'm working with is essential.   I gotta say: Your help saved me last night.  _Saved_ me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136787/discussion-between-jmb277-and-r-s).